# DateTime conversion in iOS when device's timezone change

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I get time in EDT from my server in format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss for instance 2014-05-21T09:30:00. I convert these to NSDate and save in sqlite on iphone using code below

```
NSString *strDate = @"2014-05-21T09:30:00";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EDT"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:strDate];
```

It works fine until I change the timezone on the device. If I change time on device time gets messed up. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

1. Device's timezone is Eastern and I save 8:00AM
2. I change device's timezone to Pacific and time changes to 5:00AM
3. I have an update process that updates all datetime values again and it goes back to 8AM
4. I now change device's timezone to Eastern and time goes to 11AM
5. I run the update process again and time goes back to 8AM

How can I save these times so no matter which timezone users is in, they always see eastern time.

Thanks,

D.

Comment: If you are using `NSLog` or the debugger `po` to inspect the date objects, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: The date object will always (if properly initialized) dump a value for the GMT/UTC timezone.  As trojanfoe says, "Messed up" how??

Comment: I updated post with 1.-5 steps explaining the behavior I am seeing.

Comment: *How* do you save the NSDate in the SQLite database?

Answer (score 1):

`NSDate` itself doesn't know about timezone; it's just a simple wrapper around a double value, which represents the number of seconds since some fixed time (I think Jan 1 2001 or something) UTC.

What you need is a `NSDateFormatter`, similar to the one you use to parse the date, to transform the `NSDate` into an `NSString` using the EDT timezone.

Comment: @user3573411 did this answer your question?